# Trouble filtering unique ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

Setup: `leftItems` & `rightItems` are arrays of 5 digit ID's. `matchedItems` is an array of all those ID's - there a lots of results with the same ID. `$matches` is a div to which I want to append results ONLY IF a result with that ID has not been added to the list.

PROBLEM: I keep getting div's with the same ID in `$matches`! However, i know my  filter does SOMETHING because if I add `.toString` to the existence check like  this: `matchedItems.indexOf(litem.toString())`, I get more results. My check 
gets it down to 2 or 3 results w/the same ID, but not to just 1 like i want.

```
leftItems.forEach(function (litem) {
    rightItems.forEach(function (ritem) {
        if (litem === ritem) {
            var itemDiv = $('.results.left a[provider-id="' + litem + '"]');
            var miniMe = itemDiv.clone();

            if ( matchedItems.indexOf(litem) === -1 ){
                $matches.append(miniMe);
                matchedItems.push(litem);
            } else { 
                console.log('element exists with id: ' + litem);
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to find values that are identical across two or more arrays, there are already libraries out there to do this for you. For example: https://lodash.com/docs#intersection

_.intersection([1, 2], [4, 2], [2, 1]);
// → [2]

from this result you can redraw whatever you need in the frontend.

To be honest i your example is a bit confusing and although I can think of many solutions to your problem im not sure i really understand your usecase

Edit: Based off your comment, you should follow Michaels advice and first use concat on both arrays, then a 3rd party unique() function (in his, and my case, we both use lodash, its great)

Comment: To clarify, I have 2 arrays of ID numbers, for example [ 10, 20, 30, 40 ] and [ 10, 25, 30, 45 ]. I want to append only UNIQUE ones, so I want  something like [ 10, 20, 25, 30, 40, 45 ]. However I can't filter out all the duplicates, and I get something like [ 10, 10, 20, 25, 30, 30, 40, 45 ]

Comment: `_.uniq( [].concat(leftItems).concat(rightItems) ).sort()` creates a new array, concatenates your two input arrays to it, makes a new array with only the unique elements, then sorts the result. See https://lodash.com/docs#uniq for more info.

Comment: BTW @ttante when you add a clarification like the one above, the recommended thing is to update the question with the new information. That way the question is complete and can stand on its own without people having to refer to comments to get the full picture.

Comment: Thanks Michael will definitely do that in the future! Looking forward to utilizing lodash more often.